# Initializing const variables in C

Tags: c, initialization

I want to build two libraries **lib1.a** and **lib2.a**.

**lib2.a** is in top level, it can only share with **lib1.a** global data and not the header files. Then **lib1.a** can use these data using the `extern` keyword.

The difficulty that I found is: I want to initialize a constant in a **file1.c** inside **lib1.a** with the data defined in **lib2.a**.

Example:

```
//lib1.a->file1.c:
const My_Var_Type My_Var = {
    .field1 = data1,
    .field2 = data2,
    .field3 = data3,
    .field4 = data4
};
```

Now `data1` through `data4` should be gotten from **lib2.a**, I declared them as a constant but no way! the compiler generates this error:

```
   initializer element is not constant
```

Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Please make an [mcve], including your makefile or otherwise complete information on how you build.

Comment: A simple solution is to use C++ compilation and declare `data1` etc.as `extern "C"`.  The semantics of `const` in C++ differ from that of C such that this code is then legal.  I'd post that as an answer except the language police would down-vote it for suggesting C++ as a solution to a C question.  They may be right, but perhaps C++ is what you need any way.

Comment: @Clifford interesting suggestion. To not bothered with compilation and to be very type relaxed I recommend PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: Instead of initializing a `const` with _data_, initializing a `const` with a _constant_.  For more info, best to see the code that defines/declares, `data1`, etc.

Comment: @P__J__ the suggestion of C++ was due to its simple interoperability with C since the libraries lib1.a and lib2.a have a C linkage interface. Using those libraries might not be so straightforward with other languages.

Comment: Do read the description of tags instead of wildly adding them. Your question has nothing to do with [tag:compiler-construction].

Comment: @P__J__, I should use C  compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant initialize the static storage objects (global ones or having attribute `static`) using non constant expressions - ie another variables for example. It does not matter if those objects are `const` ot not

This is illegal:

```
extern int data1, data2, data3, data4;

typedef struct
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
    int field3;
    int field4;
}My_Var_Type;

  const My_Var_Type My_Var=
     {
      .field1 = data1,   /* wrong */
      .field2 = data2,   /* wrong */
      .field3 = data3,   /* wrong */
      .field4 = data4,   /* wrong */
     };


int main()
{
    /* .... */
    return 0;
}
```

You can initialize this way automatic variables.

```
int main()
{
  const My_Var_Type My_Var=
     {
      .field1 = data1,   /* good */  
      .field2 = data2,   /* good */
      .field3 = data3,   /* good */
      .field4 = data4,   /* good */
     };

    /* ....*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So it's impossible. Do you have any other suggestion?